# How to debug and find variables on twig themes

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to create a theme for a drupal web site, but I find it difficult to get variables.
Here is an example:
to get an image form a view I wrote this line

```
row.content['#row']._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value
```

How can we define this path ? even with **vardumper** and **dump** it's not possible to get this information!!
Is there any effective way to determine how variables are structred ?

Comment: IMO trying to 'theme' a view in this manner is not advised. Either make use of the various field formatters, or use a rendered entity (Content) with a view mode to dictate markup and output.

Comment: Can you give me more detail please? or are there any resources or examples that I can get inspired from?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug a twig file is to use xdebug then `{{ devel_breakpoint() }}`

Here is how to install it: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/xdebug-debugger.

Once you figured how to reach your variable using the debugger in PHP syntax, you just need to translate the arrows or get method to twig. It takes a bit of practice, but helps to reach your variable with ease.

But in your particular case, I think using what Views provides as formatter seems to be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you recommand me any particular resources where I can learn how to create advanced drupal themes and respecting the best practices?

Comment: i think the Drupal documentation are the best things to read https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal